# Почему данная функция не выводит массив?

Tags: javascript, функции, map, filter

Почему данная функция не выводит массив целых, положительных чисел возведённых в степень 2?

```js
const squareList = (arr) => {
  arr.filter(elem=>
  Number.isInteger(elem)&&elem>0)
  .map(elem=>Math.pow(elem, 2));
  return arr;
  
};


const squaredIntegers = squareList([-3, 4.8, 5, 3, -3.2]);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const squareList = (arr) => {
  return arr.filter(elem => Number.isInteger(elem) && elem > 0).map(elem => Math.pow(elem, 2));
};
console.log(squareList([-3, 4.8, 5, 3, -3.2]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что, метод `map` не изменяет итерируемый массив, а создает новый.

```js
const squareList = (arr) => {
  const result = arr.filter(elem=>
  Number.isInteger(elem)&&elem>0)
  .map(elem=>Math.pow(elem, 2));
  return result;
  
};


const squaredIntegers = squareList([-3, 4.8, 5, 3, -3.2]);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```